# maven removes a CSS property from a CSS file during the build

Tags: css, maven

I have a very strange situation.

In my maven project I have a CSS file with the following rule:

```
.user_form{
    background-image: none !important;
    margin-bottom: 8px !important;
    width: 30px !important;
    height: 30px !important;
    border: 1px solid #d5d5dc;
    border-radius: 3px;
    font-family: DPL_Iconfont;
    color: #47bdb5;
    justify-content: center;
    display: flex;
    background: #F9F9FA;
    align-items: center;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
}
```

The CSS file is valid e has noerrors.
If I run mvn package and open the generated WAR, the CSS file has the following rule:

```
.user_form{
    background-image: none !important;
    margin-bottom: 8px !important;
    width: 30px !important;
    height: 30px !important;
    border: 1px solid #d5d5dc;
    border-radius: 3px;
    font-family: DPL_Iconfont;
    color: #47bdb5;
    justify-content: center;
    background: #F9F9FA;
    align-items: center;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
}
```

The property display: flex; is removed.

I can't understand what's happening.

If I move the property at the end of the block as following

```
 .user_form{
        background-image: none !important;
        margin-bottom: 8px !important;
        width: 30px !important;
        height: 30px !important;
        border: 1px solid #d5d5dc;
        border-radius: 3px;
        font-family: DPL_Iconfont;
        color: #47bdb5;
        justify-content: center;
        background: #F9F9FA;
        align-items: center;
        display: -ms-flexbox;
        display: flex;
    }
```

the maven build does not remove the property and the CSS file remains the same.

Comment: The *most recent* version of the property `display` should *always* be listed last anyway.

Comment: See - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Backwards_Compatibility_of_Flexbox

Comment: ok I understood how I have to use the flexbox, but the problem is why maven removes that CSS property

Comment: Because although `display: -ms-flexbox;` won't throw an error because it''s not technically invalid it still **overrides** the previous `display:flex` and so that is not parsed.

Comment: Ok, but why if I put display: flex after the property display: -ms-flexbox;
shouldn't I still find only one property?

Comment: Because IE10 does not recognise `display:flex` so it ignores it but it will recognise the older property and apply it.

Comment: Like I said, the second `display` cancels out the first. Just put them in the right order as standard. Then move on.